# Drupal/CiviContribute & Metatags

Tags: drupal, civicontribute, contribution-page

We are running Drupal 7 and the Metatag module, which is working as intended on the rest of the site.

While our contribution pages are working fine, they do not contain the description and keyword meta tags that appear on the other pages on our site.

Can someone point me in the right direction to get this functioning?

Thank you!
Rachel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To anyone else trying to do this:

- Install/enable Metatag module
- Install/enable Context module
- Enable Metatag:Context submodule

In Metatag module settings you will now be able to enter either the path or the query string to set the tags.  To make query strings work, you will also need to configure those in the Context module setup.